# Managing the accessabiliy of data item in a web app

Tags: security, web-applications

I am about to start a new project with Flask+AngularJS, first time experience with such mix. But my questions are not related to my choice of platform/framework.

There would be loads of situations where some lists of items are presented to user, and user can click on one of the items to browse it. Naturally, such functionality would be provided by passing to the client a list of item database ids, and browsing would happen by requesting item info by its id. However, I am uneasy about enabling user retrieving some information by its it. There could be cases when a user is not entitled to open certain item.

So, I have two questions:

- Is it good idea to share database object ids to the client? It's definitely easier, but doesn't it reveal too much info for a malicious logged-in user? An alternative could be generating a unique ID for every clickable item, and keeping at the server side a dictionary what those ids mean. Feels like pretty big hassle (not to mention extra processing overhead), but maybe it's worth the pain?
- If I'd go with revealing the item database ids to the client, then I should still keep a list of the items that were shown to the client (in this session), and let the user browse only those. Thus, any attempt to browse an item by entering its id directly in URL (or POST request) would be stopped, if the user "had no legal way to access it". Is there any name for this technique, so I could read on the best practices how to implement it?